# Chrome Extension get current theme background

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome theme that changes the new tab page, and I would like to get the image background of the current theme. I found that the theme image can be accessed at `chrome://theme/IDR_THEME_NTP_BACKGROUND` and included `"permissions": ["chrome://theme/IDR_THEME_NTP_BACKGROUND"]` in my manifest file.

In the index.html file, I include the image with `<img src="chrome://theme/IDR_THEME_NTP_BACKGROUND">` but the image does not render.

How can I retrieve the current theme background, and use it inside the extension code?

Comment: chrome-search://theme/IDR_THEME_NTP_BACKGROUND simply isn't accessible by any page or extension.

Comment: In Firefox there is [browser.theme.getCurrent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/theme/getCurrent) as part of WebExtensions API standard but it is not implemented in Chrome :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't do that.

- There is no api for chrome extension to get theme background
- Chrome extension can't access files in another theme
- Override newtab page can't access chrome:// files
- Chrome extension can only access files from other extensions if these files are marked `"web_accessible_resources"`

Comment: 6 years later and it seems it's still impossible to create a browser extension with a UI that matches the browser. So much for progress!